# How can I remove header from csv or txt file?

Tags: python, csv

I chose csv's specific column and converted it to txt.

The selected column name is 'id' (header)
and I don't know how to remove that 'id' from txt.

This is my code..

```
import csv
with open('garosu_example.csv') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)

input_file = "garosu_example.csv"
output_file = "garosu_example.txt"

id = ['id']
selected_column_index = []

with open(input_file, 'r', newline='') as csv_in_file:
    with open(output_file, 'w', newline='/n') as csv_out_file:
        freader = csv.reader(csv_in_file)
        fwriter = csv.writer(csv_out_file)
        header = next(freader)
        for index_value in range(len(header)):
            if header[index_value] in id:
                selected_column_index.append(index_value)
        print(id)
        fwriter.writerow(id)
        for row_list in freader:
            row_list_output = []
            for index_value in selected_column_index:
                row_list_output.append(row_list[index_value])
            print(row_list_output)
            f.writer.writerow(row_list_output)
```

How can I remove 'id'(header) from txt file?

If I remove header in csv, output txt file is emptyT_T

[image: Here is an example of my csv file]

Comment: How does the csv file look like?

Comment: I edited my question. I have linked it's img.

Comment: Anyway, i answered already

Comment: If any of the answers solved your question, it's good practice to upvote them and accept the best one (I see you've already done this). The latter also grants you a small rep bonus :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can skip the first line and replace the document with everything after:

```
with open(file) as f:
    with open("file_without_header.csv",'w') as nh:
        next(f)
        for l in f:
            nh.write(l)
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way with `readlines` and `writelines`:

```
with open('filename.csv') as f:
    with open('no_header.csv', 'w') as f2:
        f2.writelines(f2.readlines()[1:])
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way you can try is to use pandas to manipulate your csv file.

An example of using pandas to manipulate the csv file would be

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("<Your-CSV-file>", columns=["id", "name", "longitude", "latitude"])
df.drop(columns=["id"])  ## this will drop the column named id
df.to_csv("<Your-New-CSV-file-Path>", index=None, header=True)
```

Hope it helps.